# Azure Search Wildcard on ideographic (Chinese) language

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-search, chinese-locale

We are building a search engine that has both English and Chinese characters. English searches work fine with wildcards e.g. washe* return results as expected. Executing a mixed search on Chinese only search with a wildcard fails. Here are two examples:

Example 1:

The following query will return matches with 刮水 but ignores the "frog*", removing the * works, but only for exact matches.

```
https://notarealurl.search.windows.net/indexes/parts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&queryType=full&search=frog* 刮水
```

Example 2:

The following query returns no results, remove the * and it works fine.

```
https://notrealurl.search.windows.net/indexes/parts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&queryType=full&search=刮水*
```

Is there a method for search Chinese characters in Azure Search with wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the expected results of querying 刮水*?
What language analyzer is configured for this field. Standard analyzer segments CJK words into characters. Can you try to configure Chinese linguistic analyzer? I'd recommend to read the following documents before making changes to analyzer.

[Analyzers for text processing in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers)

[Language analyzers in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/language-support)

If a custom analyzer is needed, [Custom analyzers in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#AnalyzerTable)